# Cannot use typescript Array<T> with lodash?

Tags: typescript, lodash

if I try to use typescript Array with let's say 'some' or 'sumBy' I get error that T[] is not assignable to List | Dictionary. How do I get around that?

```
this.balanceTotal = _.sumBy(this.invoices, i => i.balance);
```

This does not work either

```
let a = _.castArray(this.invoices);
this.balanceTotal = _.sumBy(a, i => i.balance);
```

[image]

Comment: what is the type of `balanceTotal` ?

Comment: balanceTotal is number. It does not work even without assigment, it immediatelly reports error.

Comment: can you add the moew code or create a plunker